# ngnix transfers data to a unix domain socket incompletely

Tags: php, linux, nginx, unix-socket

My application is listening on a unix domain socket (UDS) for incoming data while nginx is sending data using PHP. Sending smaller data chunks of several KB works perfectly but as soon as it gets to certain limit, the browser gets the error `504 Gateway Time-out`, nginx logs

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response
>   header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET
>   /foo/bar.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "localhost"

The socket still gets some data (always cut at around 1.5 MB) and replies but the webserver doesn't seem to get the response.
Are there any UDS stream limits or nginx variables that must be adjusted?

PHP code:

```
public function send ($msg)
{
    $str = "{$msg}".chr(27);

    $ret = socket_write($this->socket, $str, strlen($str));

    if ($ret == FALSE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $response = "";

        while (($chunk = socket_read($this->socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $response .= $chunk;

            if (substr($chunk, -1) == chr(27))
                break;
        }

        //close the connection
        if ($this->connected !== false)
        {
            socket_shutdown($this->socket);
            socket_close($this->socket);
            $this->connected = false;
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: That "504 gateway timeout" means, that the loadbalancer (or proxy) has dropped the TCP connection, even if there was still outstanding traffic.  I should not happen with a direct connection.

Comment: You should show your code. I had a really difficult time programming a handler in a module several years ago. Nginx did not make it easy and there docs left a lot to be desired.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for staters Nginx has nothing to do with this question it's that is quite clearly PHP sending and receiving data.

It is more than likely your remote system is not closing the socket at the correct time or is just taking far to long to respond.

```
while (($chunk = socket_read($this->socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ)) !== FALSE)
{
    $response .= $chunk;
    if (substr($chunk, -1) == chr(27))
    break;
}
```

This code block has the potential to be an infinite loop with this code if the remote system has not closed the connection/socket and told you about it will keep trying to read and be waiting for 2048 (Bit's or Bytes - I can never remember which size it asks for sure a comment will inform) of data to come through or the socket to close before the read is finished.

So a couple of things to try to lower your read bytes set it to something like `128`, put in a timer to your socket (requires async programming in PHP) read so kill it after 28 seconds give your code 2 more seconds to execute (safely exit). or use  `set_time_limit` to increase your time limit.

If you do increase your time limit you will need to increase the amount of time nginx is allowed to get the response from the connection to PHP to do this set your `fastcgi_read_timeout`

Comment: That was it. My application did not close the connection properly (not PHP). Due to a bug it worked only for short streams not exceeding the buffer size. Thanks!

Comment: @ScepticalJule could you mark this as the answer then if it answered your question with the statement `your remote system is not closing the socket at the correct time`

Answer (score 0):

The error states that connection timed out between Nginx and upstream server.

Does your request take more then 1 minute to complete?

Try to change the nginx location as per follow and read about [fastcgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout)

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```